# django admin keyerror: key not found in form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a strange problem with my form in django admin.

I have defined my form, model and modeladmin:

```
import datetime
from cmsplugin_news.admin import NewsAdmin as OldNewsAdmin
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from news.models import News


class NewNewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('title', 'is_published', 'pub_date', 'is_featured')


class NewsAdmin(OldNewsAdmin ):
    fields = ('title', 'is_published', 'pub_date', 'is_featured')
    form = NewNewsForm


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(_('Published'), default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Publication date'), default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(_('Featured'), default=False)

admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

All fields in the model seem to appear as well in the admin and form. But when I head to /en/admin/news/news/4/, I'm getting the following KeyError: key "is_featured" not found in form

Full stacktrace here https://dpaste.de/9yV3

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So what is `OldNewsAdmin`?

Comment: from cmsplugin_news.admin import NewsAdmin as OldNewsAdmin -> https://bitbucket.org/zerok/cmsplugin-news/src/fff7aaae16662f2c6b3832bc786300163b647cf8/cmsplugin_news/admin.py?at=default

Comment: Check / add readonly_fields = ('field_name', 'other_field') to your ModelAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a collision with other property. Changing the name made it work.

Comment: For others who may be getting this error for no apparent reason it came up for me when I was using get_fieldsets in my admin.  I had an admin working perfectly then tried to move a M2M field from an inline into the fields of a fieldset.  But instead of telling me an appropriate error, it gave me this keyerror (Key X not found in Form).  The actual problem is that a "ManyToManyField with through model can't be used in admin": https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12203 Hope this saves someone some time!

Comment: Well, since I just came across my own comment again I thought I'd add that it applies to Django 1.8.  Not sure about newer versions.

Comment: I have used M2M fields with "through" model in django versions from 1.4 upwards, never had any problem in django admin. Besides of that one from my original post. It does not look like "ManyToManyField with through model can't be used in admin"